# Getting error while building package checking for set-gcc... no

Tags: linux, ubuntu, build, compilation, debian

I've tried to build some packages from source code. I've been solving many error so far but I reach one point where I can't find any solution even after spending hours of searching online. I think the problem is the line "checking for set-gcc... no" but what is "set-gcc". I've tried "apt install set-gcc" but it is not the package name.

`build@shell:~/posixlib$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/app set CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/posixlib/lib" set LDFLAGS="$HOME/posixlib/lib/libgnu.a"
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for set-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in /home/build/posixlib': configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables See config.log' for more details`

Comment: Why are you ignoring the warnings?

Comment: I don't know about those arguments. Can you give me an example?